# Deleting nodes in a linked list in c

Tags: c, string, linked-list, keyboard

currently i am having this little issue with my code.
I have to delete certain nodes of a liked list which contains the same string that the user enters by keyboard. I used this guy code as a template:
https://codeforwin.org/2018/05/c-program-to-delete-all-nodes-by-key-in-linked-list.html
The problem that I am having is that for some kind of reason te method is errasing some of the information of the previous node in the list.
Here is my code:

```
void  wificollector_delete_net(struct access_point *l)
{
    char* dESSID;
    int i=0;
    dESSID=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    struct access_point *delete;
    struct access_point *prev;
    delete=(struct access_point *)malloc(sizeof(struct access_point)*50);
    prev=(struct access_point *)malloc(sizeof(struct access_point)*50);
    printf("Indicate the ESSID (between “”):\n");
    scanf(" %s", dESSID);
    printf("%s\n",dESSID);
    prev=NULL;
    delete=l->next;
    while(delete!=NULL && strcmp(delete->ESSID,dESSID)==0){
        prev=delete;
        delete=delete->next;
        free(prev->MAC);
        free(prev->ESSID);
        free(prev->modo);
        free(prev->cifrado);
        free(prev);
        i++;
    }

    while(delete!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(delete->ESSID,dESSID)==0){
            if(prev!=NULL){
                prev->next=delete->next;
            }
            free(prev->MAC);
            free(prev->ESSID);
            free(prev->modo);
            free(prev->cifrado);
            free(prev);
            delete=prev->next;
            i++;
        }else{
            prev=delete;
            delete=delete->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That code leaks like a sieve. C isn't Java. You don't have to `malloc` *everything*.  And `delete->!=NULL` isn't even valid C code. To clean things up considerably I would start by moving the gathering of the essid you're wanting to remove *out* of this function, and pass it in as an argument. Make this just do one thing: search and destroy, [like this RG solution](https://pastebin.com/sJfPXCKd).

Comment: Really appreciate your help, sorry if you see really newby errors, I have been using c for less than 4 months and I am pretty much a baby programming.